# Как сократить/улучшить js код?

Tags: javascript, gulp

Вечер добрый, помогите пожалуйста сократить/улучшить javascript код.

```js
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    /* html */
    gulp.watch(paths.watch.html, { usePolling: true }, gulp.series('html')).on('all', function(event, file, stats) {
        if (event === 'change') {
            console.log(chalk `{yellow.bold File modified} [{magenta ${file}}] file changed size to {cyan ${stats.size} byte}`);
        } else if (event === 'add') {
            console.log(chalk `{green.bold File added} [{magenta ${file}}]`);
        } else if (event === 'unlink') {
            console.log(chalk `{red.bold File deleted} [{magenta ${file}}]`);
        } else {
            console.log('else');
        }
    });
    /* styles */
    gulp.watch(paths.watch.styles, { usePolling: true }, gulp.series('styles')).on('all', function(event, file, stats) {
        if (event === 'change') {
            console.log(chalk `{yellow.bold File modified} [{magenta ${file}}] file changed size to {cyan ${stats.size} byte}`);
        } else if (event === 'add') {
            console.log(chalk `{green.bold File added} [{magenta ${file}}]`);
        } else if (event === 'unlink') {
            console.log(chalk `{red.bold File deleted} [{magenta ${file}}]`);
        } else {
            console.log('else');
        }
    });
    /* script */
    gulp.watch(paths.watch.script, { usePolling: true }, gulp.series('script')).on('all', function(event, file, stats) {
        if (event === 'change') {
            console.log(chalk `{yellow.bold File modified} [{magenta ${file}}] file changed size to {cyan ${stats.size} byte}`);
        } else if (event === 'add') {
            console.log(chalk `{green.bold File added} [{magenta ${file}}]`);
        } else if (event === 'unlink') {
            delete cached.caches.script[path.resolve(file)];
            remember.forget('script', path.resolve(file));
            console.log(chalk `{red.bold File deleted} [{magenta ${file}}]`);
        } else {
            console.log('else');
        }
    });
    /* pngSprites */
    gulp.watch(paths.watch.pngSprites, { usePolling: true }, gulp.series('pngSprites')).on('all', function(event, file, stats) {
        if (event === 'change') {
            console.log(chalk `{yellow.bold File modified} [{magenta ${file}}] file changed size to {cyan ${stats.size} byte}`);
        } else if (event === 'add') {
            console.log(chalk `{green.bold File added} [{magenta ${file}}]`);
        } else if (event === 'unlink') {
            delete cached.caches.pngSprites[path.resolve(file)];
            remember.forget('pngSprites', path.resolve(file));
            console.log(chalk `{red.bold File deleted} [{magenta ${file}}]`);
        } else {
            console.log('else');
        }
    });
    /* svgSprites */
    gulp.watch(paths.watch.svgSprites, { usePolling: true }, gulp.series('svgSprites')).on('all', function(event, file, stats) {
        if (event === 'change') {
            console.log(chalk `{yellow.bold File modified} [{magenta ${file}}] file changed size to {cyan ${stats.size} byte}`);
        } else if (event === 'add') {
            console.log(chalk `{green.bold File added} [{magenta ${file}}]`);
        } else if (event === 'unlink') {
            delete cached.caches.svgSprites[path.resolve(file)];
            remember.forget('svgSprites', path.resolve(file));
            console.log(chalk `{red.bold File deleted} [{magenta ${file}}]`);
        } else {
            console.log('else');
        }
    });
    /* svgSymbols */
    gulp.watch(paths.watch.svgSymbols, { usePolling: true }, gulp.series('svgSymbols')).on('all', function(event, file, stats) {
        if (event === 'change') {
            console.log(chalk `{yellow.bold File modified} [{magenta ${file}}] file changed size to {cyan ${stats.size} byte}`);
        } else if (event === 'add') {
            console.log(chalk `{green.bold File added} [{magenta ${file}}]`);
        } else if (event === 'unlink') {
            delete cached.caches.svgSymbols[path.resolve(file)];
            remember.forget('svgSymbols', path.resolve(file));
            console.log(chalk `{red.bold File deleted} [{magenta ${file}}]`);
        } else {
            console.log('else');
        }
    });
    /* copyImages */
    gulp.watch(paths.watch.copyImages, gulp.series('copyImages')).on('all', function(event, file, stats) {
        if (event === 'change') {
            console.log(chalk `{yellow.bold File modified} [{magenta ${file}}] file changed size to {cyan ${stats.size} byte}`);
        } else if (event === 'add') {
            console.log(chalk `{green.bold File added} [{magenta ${file}}]`);
        } else if (event === 'unlink') {
            console.log(chalk `{red.bold File deleted} [{magenta ${file}}]`);
        } else {
            console.log('else');
        }
    });
    /* copyFonts */
    gulp.watch(paths.watch.copyFonts, gulp.series('copyFonts'));
});
```

Comment: чем отличаются секции кода?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, полями за которыми наблюдает `watch` и `caches`, например `gulp.watch(paths.watch.svgSprites,` и `gulp.watch(paths.watch.pngSprites,`

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, на телефоне фиг сравнишь :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, на компе тоже не особо: еще оказывается в кэш не везде ходят

Comment: Не везде есть delete cached.caches.разные названия[path.resolve(file)]; remember.forget('разные названия', path.resolve(file));

Answer (score 0):

```js
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  const watchers = {
    html: './app/templates/**/[^_]*.*',
    styles: './app/scss/**/[^_]*.{scss,css}',
    script: './app/js/**/[^_]*.js',
    pngSprites: './app/img/sprites/pngSprites/*.png',
    cssSvgSprites: './app/img/sprites/svgSprites/cssSvgSprites/*.svg',
    stackSvgSprites: './app/img/sprites/svgSprites/stackSvgSprites/*.svg',
    symbolSvgSprites: './app/img/sprites/svgSprites/symbolSvgSprites/*.svg',
    copyImages: './app/img/content/**/[^_]*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,svg,webp}',
    copyFonts: './app/fonts/*.{eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}',
  };
  for (let key in watchers) {
    gulp.watch(watchers[key], {
      usePolling: true
    }, gulp.series(key)).on('all', function(event, file, stats) {
      if (event === 'change') {
        console.log(chalk `{yellow.bold File modified} [{magenta ${file}}] file changed size to {cyan ${stats.size} byte}`);
      } else if (event === 'add') {
        console.log(chalk `{green.bold File added} [{magenta ${file}}]`);
      } else if (event === 'unlink') {
        if (key === 'script' || key === 'pngSprites' || key === 'cssSvgSprites') {
          delete cached.caches[`${key}`][path.resolve(file)];
          remember.forget(`${key}`, path.resolve(file));
        }
        console.log(chalk `{red.bold File deleted} [{magenta ${file}}]`);
      } else {
        console.log('else');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]